# Error checking for if a person enters an incorrect name

Tags: c#, error-checking

How would I check for errors. If a person enters an incorrect name or doesnt spell it correctly I would like for a messagebox.show to display a message stating "Incorrect name or spelling"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Andrea;
        String Brittany;
        String Eric;
        if (textBox1.Text == ("Andrea"))
            Commission.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) / 10).ToString();
        if (textBox1.Text == ("Brittany"))
            Commission.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) / 10).ToString();
        if (textBox1.Text ==("Eric"))
            Commission.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) / 10).ToString();

        {

        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to keep a list or 'dictionary' of correct names.

Then, you can match the text against the entries in the dictionary.

Code would look similar to the following:

```
HashSet<string> correctNames = ;// initialize the set with the names you want

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (correctNames.Contains(textBox1.Text))
        Commission.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) / 10).ToString();
    else 
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The speling of the naem " + textBox1.Text + " was incorect", "Bad Spelling Error");
    }
}
```

<sub>*You probably want to use correct spelling in your implementation.*</sub>

Have a look at [the documentation for `HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to get a better idea of how to use it.

Comment: Haha nice! Good recommendation on HashSet as well, the lookup is probably faster than list.Contains()

Comment: @SwDev, yeah, the look up will be a bit faster.  But the time difference will be minimal on any small set.

Answer (score 1):

This will check if any name in the list equals the textBox entered name:

```
List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

nameList.Add("Andrea");
nameList.Add("Brittany");
nameList.Add("Eric");

if (nameList.Contains(textBox1.Text))
{
    //Process name here.
}
else
{
    //Show messagebox here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw all the names in a collection, like a List or Dictionary, then use the [.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx) method. That should provide a neater solution.